# Check if a matrix contains a number

Tags: ocaml

I want to check if a matrix of type [[a,b,c][d,e,f]] contains a specific number.
I'm having trouble accessing the list inside the list.

```
let matrix = [[1;2;3]; [4;5;6]];;

let rec contains mat x = match mat with
| [] -> false
| h::t -> if (h=x) then true else contains t x;;
```

This work on a one-dimensional list, but I'm just too much of a newbie to get it to work on a two-dimensional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, your function `contains` is `List.mem` in the standard library (not that there is anything wrong with reimplementing it to learn OCaml).
Also, `if (h=x) then true else contains t x` is usually written `(h=x) || contains t x`.

---

As for your problem, you need to iterate over each sublist of the matrix (presumably representing a row), and for each row check if it contains the number you're looking for :

```
# let rec mat_contains mat x = match mat with
    | [] -> false
    | row::tl -> contains row x || mat_contains tl x;;
val mat_contains : 'a list list -> 'a -> bool = <fun>

# mat_contains matrix 4;;
- : bool = true
```

---

As an aside, here it is written using functions in the standard library :

```
# let mat_contains2 mat x = List.exists (List.mem x) mat;;
val mat_contains2 : 'a list list -> 'a -> bool = <fun>

# mat_contains2 matrix 4;;
- : bool = true
```